# How to put a condition on a query

Tags: 7, blocks, database

in my custom module, i am executing a query.

```
global $user;
$id = $user->uid;
print_r($id);
$query = db_query('SELECT n.nid, c.uid, n.title, f.body_value, fm.uri
FROM challenges c
LEFT JOIN node n ON n.nid = c.cid
LEFT JOIN field_data_body f ON n.nid = f.entity_id
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_challenge_pic fp ON n.nid = fp.entity_id
LEFT JOIN file_managed fm ON fp.field_challenge_pic_fid = fm.fid ');
**// WHERE c.cid = $id ');**
```

when the where clause is commented out the query runs fine. I check it using:

```
foreach($query as $q)
{
            print_r($q);
}
```

But when i add the where clause i get an error: Syntax error or access violation...on the line where i write the where clause. How can i achieve this. Thanks

Comment: First things first, watch this [Acquia video about SQL Injection](http://www.acquia.com/resources/acquia-tv/conference/identifying-and-protecting-against-sql-injection-drupal-july-12-2012). If you don't understand 100% what it's saying, keep watching it over and over again until you do :) Once you understand SQL injection, and how it's combated in Drupal, your code will naturally change. If you still get the error once you've made the changes, edit the question and someone will be able to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [db_select()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7) is recommended to use in D7, you  can still use [db_query()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7) using named placeholders.

```
$result = db_query('SELECT n.nid, c.uid, n.title, f.body_value, fm.uri
                    FROM challenges c
                    LEFT JOIN node n ON n.nid = c.cid
                    LEFT JOIN field_data_body f ON n.nid = f.entity_id
                    LEFT JOIN field_data_field_challenge_pic fp ON n.nid = fp.entity_id
                    LEFT JOIN file_managed fm ON fp.field_challenge_pic_fid = fm.fid 
                    WHERE c.cid = :cid', array(':cid' => $id)); 

if ($result) {
    while ($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
      // Do something with:
      //    $row['nid']
      //    $row['title']
    }
}
```

It prevents SQL injection also.

Comment: @Sithu...now no error is showing but the only the query is displayed ..the results are not...however when removing the condition even the results are displayed like the title(c.title), body(f.body_value) and so on...what is happening here. I wrote the same query in php myadmin its working fine

Comment: @Shradha, I updated my example. I hope you would do like that. With or without condition will have different results. Are you sure you have some records with `WHERE c.cid = xxx`.

Comment: @Sithu...thanks..i will try that now...and yes i have checked and rechecked the tables that there are records with c.cid = xxx...

Answer (score 3):

Clive's comment is right.  You should understand the reasons why, however,  I will give you the short answer ;)

Use `db_select()`

```
$query = db_select('challenges', 'c');
$query->fields('c');
$query->condition('c.cid', $id, '='); 
$result = $query->execute();
```